# Connecting iphone via virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, iphone

I'm trying to connect my iphone (ios 8.3) through virtualbox using this tutorial http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2157148
however I'm having a problem with step 7, VB doesn't show any "Apple Inc." device. Ubuntu (14.04) on the other hand, shows standard error messeges and points that iPhone is connected ( I can even browse pictures ). Can you help me ?

Comment: Have you installed the latest guest additions in your virtual machine?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes I did. I also installed latest virtualbox extensions which are needed to USB 2.0 to work

Answer (score 5):

On your Ubuntu host system, add yourself to the vboxusers group using the following command:

`sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER`

After that, logout, then login again and start the virtual machine again.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, type `lsusb`. This will present you a list of all connected USB devices. Take note of the number that looks like `baba:deda`. These are VendorID and DeviceID of your phone.
Now go to virtualbox machine settings, to USB tab, and press the "Add new empty device" button. It will add bogus device. Open it's settings and insert VendorID and DeviceID into them. Restart virtual machine. 
Now it should be working.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It still doesn't work though. When I added VendorID and DeviceID I noticed that there are quite more options.  This is what lsusb returns : `Bus 002 Device 011: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc.` and this is what i entered in USB Filter details [link](http://s16.postimg.org/ylyg4m5sl/image.png). Did I did something wrong ?

Comment: Should be OK. How exactly is it "not working"

Comment: Windows doesn't see any connected device . Same as VB